# SwiftUI: NavigationTitle display not normal with List and search field

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I work with NavigationView, NavigationTitle, List, and search field, there is an annoy display error.

The search field and NavigationTitle are not align with the List.

If the next page has searchable List, pull the next page list down and show the search bar totally, alignment will return to normal. But if you go back to the first page and pull down the search bar again, the same error will appear.

Just create a new project with Core Data, and replace the NavigationView to this code, you can easily reproduce this bug.

```swift
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach(items) { item in
          NavigationLink {
            List{}.searchable(text: $text).navigationTitle("Test")
          } label: {
            Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
          }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
      }.searchable(text: $text){}.navigationTitle("Title")
        .toolbar {
          ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            EditButton()
          }
          ToolbarItem {
            Button(action: addItem) {
              Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
            }
          }
        }
      Text("Select an item")
    }
  }
```

Or, what did I do wrong?

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found a way to circumvent this problem on my own.

We can manually set the List Style:

```
.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```

Then It shows normally.

Comment: You should use now: `
.listStyle(.insetGrouped)`